# how to force npx use yarn instead of npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, npx

I was trying to create react app with npx and it used to automatically use yarn but for some reason, it's using npm now...

I passed the `--use-yarn` flag but wasn't a success

My PC is running in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Node: 16.13.2 LTS 
npm: 8.3.2 
yarn: 1.22.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix in [#11322](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11322) thread at facebook's github repo

> This removes the --use-npm flag and adds the --use-yarn flag. It also removes the previous behavior of checking for the existence of yarn as the signal to use it as the package manager. The new behavior will be to use npm by default and to use yarn with the --use-yarn flag. 
> The goal of this PR is to remove the check on whether yarn is present in the user's path as the signal to use yarn. 
> This PR is implemented on top of #11304, since it changed some of the same files and was easier to get tests passing on top of that. I will rework this based on the outcome of that PR. For now, here's the differing commits in this PR: lukekarrys/create-react-app@lk/dev-npm-7...lk/use-npm

Answer (score 0):

## For Windows 10 users

### Creating a React App with Npx and Yarn in Windows 10

### Prerequisites

- Node.js and npm installed
- Yarn installed

### Setting the npm_config_user_agent Environment Variable

1. Right-click the Start button and select System.
2. Click on the Advanced system settings link on the left.
3. Click the Environment Variables button in the System Properties window.
4. In the Environment Variables window, scroll down to the System variables section and click on the New button.
5. In the New System Variable dialog box, enter `npm_config_user_agent` as the variable name and `yarn` as the variable value, then click OK.
6. Close the Environment Variables and System Properties windows.
7. Open a new Command Prompt window for the changes.

### Creating the React App

1. Open a Command Prompt window.
2. Run the following command to create a new React app:

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Replace `my-app` with the desired name for your project.

3. Navigate into the newly created app directory:

```bash
cd my-app
```

4. Start the development server:

```bash
yarn start
```

This will launch a development server and open a web browser displaying the default React app. The default React app will automatically reload when you change your code. The dependencies will be installed using yarn.

That's it! You should now have a React app created using `npx` with `yarn` in Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: thanks, I know that one but I was looking for a fix. also, I read that npx is best when creating react apps.